# NHibernate. Can't add two child to parent

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm

I have common parent\children scenario:

```
public class Order : AdvancedBaseOrder
{

    ICollection<ProducerRelation> producers = new List<ProducerRelation>();
    public virtual ICollection<ProducerRelation> Producers
    {
        get { return producers; }
        set { producers = value; }
    }
}

public class ProducerRelation : BaseProducerRelation
{
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
Order.hbm.xml
....
<set name="Producers" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
  <key column="order_id"/>
  <one-to-many class="ProducerRelation,Avtobus66.Core"/>
</set>
....


ProducerRelation.hbm.xml
....
 <many-to-one name="Order" class="Order, Avtobus66.Core" column="order_id" cascade="none"/>
<property name="Number" >
  <column name="number"/>
</property>
....
```

When I run this code:

```
            Order order = (Order)session.Get(typeof(Order), 23);
            var a = new ProducerRelation();
            a.Number = 6;
            a.Order = order;

            var b = new ProducerRelation();
            b.Number = 7;
            b.Order = order;

            order.Producers.Add(a);
            order.Producers.Add(b);
            session.Merge(order);
            session.Flush();
```

only one of my children is added. I know, that nhibernate is "watching" the child collection for changes, but what I do wrong? Why nhib can't add two children?

SQL:

```
 NHibernate: SELECT ... WHERE this_.id = ?p0;?p0 = 23
 NHibernate: INSERT INTO gb_avtobus66.ekbprint_producer_relation (producer_price, producer_price_clean, order_id, ekbprint_product_id, client_id, number) VALUES (?p0, ?p1, ?p2, ?p3, ?p4, ?p5);?p0 = 0, ?p1 = 0, ?p2 = 23, ?p3 = NULL, ?p4 = NULL, ?p5 = 6
 NHibernate: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: Does it work if you do a Get instead of a Load?

Comment: Sorry. I use repositories pattern, and it was my small mistake at write post. Of course Get

Comment: What does the generated SQL say? Which child object is inserted?

Comment: Did you try session.SaveOrUpdate()?

Comment: I posted SQL. I detect that second entity isn't added in list. After call second Add method, member's count  of list doesn't change!!!

Comment: What's the purpose of `session.Merge` here?

Comment: It probably isn't the source of your problem, but the `Merge()` call isn't necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is because of the fact that you're using a `set` collection type. A set is an unordered collection that contains no duplicates. So likely it's looking at the two new children and thinks that the second one is a duplicate. Make sure you override Equals/GetHashcode to indicate what is a duplicate entry.

Comment: Vadim, thanks. You're right!!! What should I do? Use bag instead of set? Or override Equals at each domain? Now I have overidden Equals at my base domain. It compare domains Id. So two new unpersisted domain are equals. It there any disadvantage of use bag in common scenario? I don't want override Equals at each domain

Comment: @Andrew, if your Equals just looks at ids, then you might as well use a bag. Your Equals method should express business rules around what is equal. It's probably fine for an Order object, but for ProducerRelation could be equal if Number is equal.

Answer (score 0):

Use get instead of Load.... :)